# How can I make the map's regions change color when hover the mouse over it?

Tags: javascript, geography

I'm using the [interactive map](http://codecanyon.net/item/interactive-world-maps/full_screen_preview/2874264) from codecanyon. I want to make a change so that the selected region changes color when the mouse is over it. I deployed an [example](http://koolbusiness.com/_/index_india.html) where this is the code that does it.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

 data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); 
 data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});var ivalue = new Array();

 var options = {
 backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:25 },
 colorAxis:  {minValue: 0, maxValue: 0,  colors: []},
 legend: 'none',    
 backgroundColor: {fill:'#FFFFFF',stroke:'#FFFFFF' ,strokeWidth:25 },   
 datalessRegionColor: '#ffc801',
 displayMode: 'regions', 
 enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
 resolution: 'provinces',
 sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 10},
 region:'IN',
 keepAspectRatio: true,
 width:600,
 height:400,
 tooltip: {textStyle: {color: '#444444'}, trigger:'focus', isHtml: false}   
 };
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization')); 
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
  if (selection.length == 1) {
  var selectedRow = selection[0].row;
  var selectedRegion = data.getValue(selectedRow, 0);
  if(ivalue[selectedRegion] != '') { document.location = ivalue[selectedRegion];  }
  }
  });
 chart.draw(data, options);
 }
 </script>
 <div id='visualization'></div>
```

Now I want the selected region to change color like in my mockup here. Can it be done?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Plnkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DvUzclRXB4l1OcuZ6yxJ?p=preview)

You can accomplish this with a css rule.
The hover rule applies to all your paths and the rect rule excludes your ocean so that only the land areas will highlight as you indicated.
Each rule is preceded by an ID selector to keep the rules only applicable to the div your map loaded within.

```
<style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    #visualization path:hover { fill: cornflowerblue; }
    #visualization rect:hover {fill:transparent;}
</style>
```

Comment: Modified the answer to exclude the ocean from the hover highlight. I assumed this would be acceptable as it seems to align with the questions intent. If not, I will remove the modification.

Comment: Thanks. It was a good answer. Now I have created a minimal [fiddle](@runDOSrun It was a good link. You may look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/Gsj27/1346/) I created for the problem with a minimal code to represent to problem. ) for my problem. I want to align the divs side by side. Now the framework seems to not let that be done in a way that I know.

Comment: It should be noted that if you countries are your regions: it will not change the fill color for the entire country. Only the land mass which you have hovered. (i.e. hovering over US mainland leaves Alaska it's previous color).

Comment: @EoghanTadhg that is a good point. I think you would definitely need to leverage JavaScript in orderto solve that issue.